# show syn-send and syn-receive statistics on windows server?

Tags: windows, sockets, server

Most of us know that Linux has an command:ss to show socket statistics, anyone know is there a similar one on windows server,has already tried to google it or how to show syn-send and syn-receive information on windows?

Comment: perfmon.exe (GUI) is the hub for stuff like that.

Comment: yes,that's it, Thanks